# Binary Search on Datasets from One Gig File and On Small File on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, dataset, nodes, assign

I'm new to Hadoop. I have a big file which won't be not updated and a bunch of small files. My intention is to put the big file on many different datanodes according to hash values of records in it. And every time I search records in a small file by dispatch them to datanodes according to hash values and then do binary search locally.

My questions are:

1. How to assign datanodes to records according to hash values of records
2. How to make sure the binary search is performed locally

***NOTE: I've figured it out by using both TotalOrderPartitioner and Mapfile.***

Comment: The question is not very clear, can you add an example, like your big file will have "abc" data , small file will have "xyz" data ?

Comment: The big data consists of about 10M entries. Each line includes a hash value and a string. The small data consists of about 100 entries in the same format. My intention is to to split big data into different datanodes according to hash value. Every time when small data comes, I split it as well. So in each datanode, I can do binary search instead of merge sort. Thanks!

Comment: Is the big file sorted by hash value ?, what are you going to be searching I mean what action will invoke your search process ? Do you need the search to done in real time ?, are you planning to use the small file like indexes ?